# Build errors in ag-grid source ts files when using ag-grid installed with bower in an AngularJs with Typescript project

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, bower, ag-grid

I have found 2 issues with the way ag-grid dependency is structured and with its documentation. Hopefully somebody can refer me to a good typescript Angular1.x samples where ag-grid is used.

I have a basic AngularJs SPA project
I installed `"ag-grid": "3.1.0"` with

`bower install ag-grid`

by adding the dependency to my bower.json in Visual Studio 2015 and as result it adds under bower_components the following structure:

`ag-grid
 |
 |-- dist
 |--src
    |
    |--ts
 |
 ...`

The problem I have is that **unless I physically delete the `/bower_components/ag-grid/src` folder**, Visual Studio will show 926 errors within ts files under that source folder. Error such as:

```
TS2345  Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type      'Grid'.
Type 'ag.grid.Grid' is not assignable to type 'ag.grid.Grid'.   TypeScript Virtual Projects C:\MyProject\bower_components\ag-grid\src\ts\grid.ts
```

and many duplicate issues between `bower_components/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.ts` and `bower_components/ag-grid/src/ts/widgets/agDropdownList.ts` such as:

```
TS2300 Build: Duplicate identifier 'AgDropdownList'
TS2300 Build: Duplicate identifier 'AgDropdownList'
```

I understand there are TS classes and other names duplicated and Visual Studio 2016 does not like that. **But is this an expected result? Why to have the sources included in a bower dependency. Is it in case I want to generate (with Gulp for example) my own dist/ag-grid.js? If so why to include then the dist/ag-grid.ts folder if it's going to conflict?**

I am not too familiar with front-end development and task-runner strategies so maybe this is a common practice and developers are supposed to delete the `/bower_components/ag-grid/src` folder.

If instead deleting the `/bower_components/ag-grid/src` folder I delete the `bower_components/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.ts`  I still get 13 errors such as

```
TS2304 Build: Cannot find name 'exports'
TS2304 Build: Cannot find name 'module'
```

and it even has a reference to `/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd" />` that is broken as there is no `typings` folder at all.

It feels as if this dependency was a little bit messy, doesn't it?

The other thing that makes me confused about ag-grid is that in the sample it says that an [AngularJs controller would need the ngGrid dependency](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/index.php). However **this dependency is not being used**. This is my example without this dependency injected:

The view:

```
<div ng-controller="app.shipments.ShipmentsController as shipments">
    <h1>Shipments</h1>
    <div ag-grid="shipments.gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

The typescript controller:

```
module app.shipments {
    'use strict';

    interface IShipmentsScope {
        gridOptions: ag.grid.GridOptions;
    }

    class ShipmentsController implements IShipmentsScope {
        static $inject = [
        ]; 
        constructor() {

        }

        gridOptions: ag.grid.GridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
                { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
                { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }
            ],
            rowData : [
                { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
                { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
                { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
            ]
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('app.shipments')
        .controller('app.shipments.ShipmentsController', ShipmentsController);
}
```

That works properly as long as my server serves the JS dependency and 2 css:

```
<link href="../bower_components/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/ag-grid/dist/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../bower_components/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js"></script>
```

I guess what I am asking for is a **clarification** on why the bower dependency is structured in such a way, what is the common practice when developing with such dependency for VS not to complain about TS errors and a clarification on whether the **agGrid dependency is necessary at all to be injected in AngularJs controllers**. :-)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead having to delete the src folder I am instructing VS2015 not to compile any TypeScript on build (and I do so with a gulp watch task), which is not ideal but saves me from seeing duplicated errors.

I did so by right click on project > Build > untick the *Compile TypeScript on build* option

I still don't know why agGrid injection in the controller is necessary for Angular 1.x according to the documentation (it is not). But this question can be closed